# C program Output Error

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int m,n;
  float cake;

  printf("Enter total kgs of cake:");
  scanf("&d", &n);

  printf("Enter the number of friends:");
  scanf("&d", &m);

  cake  = m/n;
  printf(He has to distribute %f kg cake to each of his %d friends", 
         &cake, &m);

}
```

When I run this program in codeblocks, it asks me for only to enter total kgs of cake, when I enter it and click on enter, the program just prints everything else in the printf functions below instead of asking me to enter the number of friends.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &n)` . I wonder how can compiler ignore it.

Comment: It's not the first time I see a question with `&d` instead of `%d`.

Comment: @RohanKumar: `printf(He has to distribute %f kg cake to each of his %d friends", &cake, &m);` it doesn't even compile (missing quote at start)

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Nice catch! The other printf/scanf problems can be caught  by compiling with `-Wall` flag in gcc.

Comment: That `cake = m/n;` is not going to give the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

```
scanf("&d", &n);

scanf("&d", &m);
```

You need to change it to

```
scanf("%d", &n);

scanf("%d", &m);
```

Additionally in printf function you should not pass address of variables

Answer (score 3):

The "&d" holds the address of the particular variable. So, you need to change the 
    `scanf("&d",&m)` to `scanf("%d",&m)` and `scanf("&d",&n)` to `scanf("%d",&n)`. Here `%d` is the placeholder for integer variables.
Similarly, in the final print statement the ampersand `&` prints the address not the value, so remove `&` in final printf statement

Comment: Detail, with `scanf()`, `"%d"` does not a need matching _integer variable_, it needs a _pointer_, such as `&n` which is an `int *`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code. First your `scanf()` should be like this:

```
scanf("%d", &var);
```

Next off is in your `printf` statement. In the var section, you did `&cake` and `&m` which is wrong due to the fact you are gonna print the address of the variable. To fix that, remove the `&`.